# Ayuda para eliminar una fila de una tabla con php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, bootstrap

Estoy empezando con php, html y mySQL, y resulta que me pidieron que realice una web que permita buscar, agregar y eliminar productos.
Todo iba bien hasta que llegué a la parte en la que tengo que eliminar una fila de la base de datos, agregué un pequeño boton en cada fila para que al pulsarlo se eliminara dicha fila, el problema que tengo es que al pulsar en el botón me devuelve el siguiente error:

Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\BD Practico\interfaz\BD_eliminar_productos.php on line 4
Producto eliminado con éxito

Por un lado me dice que id no está definido, que según yo lo está, y por otro me dice que el producto fue eliminado pero al revisarlo el producto sigue ahí.

Inserto el código:

Tabla:

```
<table border="0" class="row table table-hover table-1 col-lg-12 margin-top-bottom" align="center">
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Número</th>
            <th>Producto</th>
            <th>Tipo</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
    <?php
    $sql="SELECT producto_id, producto_desc, tipo_producto_desc, producto_precio
         FROM producto p, tipo_producto tp
         WHERE p.tipo_producto_id = tp.tipo_producto_id
         ORDER BY producto_id ASC";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     ?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <th><?php echo $mostrar['producto_id'] ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['producto_desc'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['tipo_producto_desc'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mostrar['producto_precio'] ?></td>
        <td width="50">
            <a href="BD_eliminar_productos.php">
                <button type="submit" name="id" value="<?php echo $mostrar['producto_id']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
            </a>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<?php
}
 ?>
</table>
```

BD_eliminar_productos.php:

```
<?php
```

include 'connect.php';

```
$id = $_POST["id"];

$eliminar = "DELETE FROM producto
            WHERE producto_id = '$id'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $eliminar) or die("Error: ".mysql_error);

if(!$resultado){
    echo 'Error al eliminar el producto';
} else{
    echo 'Producto eliminado con éxito';
}
```

mysqli_close($conexion);

Answer (score 0):

Toda tu sección del html es incorrecto, sustituyelo por

```
<form action="BD_eliminar_productos.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $mostrar['producto_id']; ?>">
    <button type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Eliminar</button>
</form>
```

Lo adecuado, ya que tienes múltiples elementos, es usar JS pero esto debe servirte.